# jQuery SerializeArray/Param get the class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that had live appended input type hiddens with a name, value, and class and they all mean something. I want to take this and post to my php the json values. So I am doing

```
var storage = $.param($('form input[type=hidden]').serializeArray(), true);
```

and that works fine, however it only gets the name, and value. I need the class also because it has a unique id stored in it, which I can't store in the name or value because those also store unique ids.

So my question/options are.

1. Can I somehow store two unique ids in the name that would be processed as such? Maybe a `{id1:1,id2:2}` or something as the name value?
2. Can I make serializeArray also get the class name?

Example of input type hidden I add

`<input type="hidden" class="photo_spot_1" name="photo_spot_5" value="../uploads/2462df38db374653720daa42b7aefec4/g6qjcn30kw_c.png">`

Notice the two different id's at the end of name and class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have an element id like `{id1:1,id2:2}` and also `serializeArray` will not get the class information from input fields but you can write your own logic to get that.

```
var data = [], obj;
$('form input[type=hidden]').each(function(){
    obj = {};
    obj[this.name] = this.value;
    obj["class"] = this.className
    data.push(obj);
});
```

Now you can use `data` which will contain each hidden input with is name/value and class information.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet will likely be to take those unique classes, and throw them onto a hidden input before you serialize your form and do your post.  This will give your server side code much easier access to these values.

Something like this:

```
$("#hiddenInput1").val($("#el1")[0].className);
var storage = $.param($('form input[type=hidden]').serializeArray(), true);
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you mean, you mean take all 3 of the ids I need and store them in 3 different inputs? I already store inputs for them.

Comment: @Steven - I may not understand, but you said you needed the class, and wanted a workaround to get the current class posted with the rest of your form.  I'm saying this will be a pain, and that the easier way will be to just throw that class value onto a *new* hidden input, *and then* do your serialize and post